# Ошибка установки pyaudio

Tags: python

Когда я пробую установить pyaudio вылетает ошибка.Pip последней версии,python тоже.Установил visual studio 2019.Помогите пожалуйста.

````
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\donan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_kbkp6uw'
       cwd: C:\Users\donan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1rxhapxn\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: Ё§¬Ґ­Ґ­ЁҐ ¬ Єа®®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: б¬. ЇаҐ¤л¤гйҐҐ ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "MS_WIN64"
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\donan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7jhogvsb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\donan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1rxhapxn\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: Ё§¬Ґ­Ґ­ЁҐ ¬ Єа®®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: б¬. ЇаҐ¤л¤гйҐҐ ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "MS_WIN64"
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\donan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1rxhapxn\\pyaudio_056748ed97de4f75b74c50b26de6e924\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\donan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7jhogvsb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\donan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Answer (score 1):

Максимальная версия python поддерживаемая библиотекой pyaudio `3.6`
Источник: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads

И вырезка оттуда соответственно:

> Microsoft Windows
>
> Install using pip:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install pyaudio
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> If pip is not already bundled with your installation of Python, get it
> here. pip will fetch and install PyAudio wheels (prepackaged
> binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official
> distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. For those versions,
> both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available.
>
> These binaries include PortAudio v19 v190600_20161030, built with
> MinGW. They support only the Windows MME API and do not include
> support for DirectX, ASIO, etc. If you require support for APIs not
> included, you will need to compile PortAudio and PyAudio.

Посмотрите в сторону установки нескольких версий python, вот пример как это можно сделать: https://dev-gang.ru/article/ustanovka-neskolkih-versii-python-v-windows-s-pomosczu-virtualenv-9h4wf77b10/

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, у меня была такая же ошибка, я скачал PyAudio отсюда [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

А затем установил через

**pip install "полный путь к файлу\файл"**

, например, у меня путь был таким C:\Users\"Имя"\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl. Это решило проблему.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало